# How to solve code duplication in the following PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, code-duplication, architecture

I have a table Inputs and a derived table Parameters

```
CREATE TABLE Configurables
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Inputs
(
  configurable integer REFERENCES Configurables( id ),
  name text,
  time timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY( configurable, name, time )
);

CREATE TABLE Parameters
(
  configurable integer,
  name text,
  time timestamp,
  value text,
  FOREIGN KEY( configurable, name, time ) REFERENCES Inputs( configurable, name, time )
);
```

The following query checks whether a parameter has been changed, or is not present yet, and inserts the parameter with a new value.

```
QString PostgreSQLQueryEngine::saveParameter( int configurable, const QString& name, const QString& value )
{
  return QString( "\
    INSERT INTO Inputs( configurable, name, time ) \
      WITH MyParameter AS \
      ( \
        SELECT configurable, name, time, value \
        FROM \
        ( \
          SELECT configurable, name, time, value \
          FROM Parameters \
          WHERE (configurable = %1) AND (name = '%2') AND time =  \
          ( \
            SELECT max( time ) \
            FROM Parameters \
            WHERE (configurable = %1) AND (name = '%2') \
          ) \
          UNION \
          SELECT %1 AS configurable, '%2' AS name, '-infinity' AS time, NULL AS value \
        )AS foo \
      ) \
      SELECT %1 AS configurable, '%2' AS name, 'now' AS time FROM MyParameter \
      WHERE time = (SELECT max(time) FROM MyParameter) AND (value <> '%3' OR value IS NULL); \
      \
    INSERT INTO Parameters( configurable, name, time, value ) \
      WITH MyParameter AS \
      ( \
        SELECT configurable, name, time, value \
        FROM \
        ( \
          SELECT configurable, name, time, value \
          FROM Parameters \
          WHERE (configurable = %1) AND (name = '%2') AND time =  \
          ( \
            SELECT max( time ) \
            FROM Parameters \
            WHERE (configurable = %1) AND (name = '%2') \
          ) \
          UNION \
          SELECT %1 AS configurable, '%2' AS name, '-infinity' AS time, NULL AS value \
        )AS foo \
      ) \
      SELECT %1 AS configurable, '%2' AS name, 'now' AS time, '%3' AS value  FROM MyParameter \
      WHERE time = (SELECT max(time) FROM MyParameter) AND (value <> '%3' OR value IS NULL); \
    " ).arg( configurable ).arg( name ).arg( value );
}
```

How should I best solve the duplication of 2 the MyParameter subqueries?

Any other tips on cleaning up a query like this

Comment: Are you inserting the same configurable, name and time in both tables. You already have a foreign key in Parameters which refers to Inputs. Do you really need de-normalization ?

Comment: Added Configurable definition. A Configurable has a list of inputs, an input can be a Parameter. I chose de-normalizing it so I can easily get an overview from the Inputs table. (there's more tables deriving from Inputs then Parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid de-normalized tables. You should use a view for easy overview of Parameter table. It would be much, much easier.

You should only use de-normalized summary table if your view isn't fast enough. But any de-normalized tables should be maintained using triggers, as otherwise you risk that this tables go out of sync.

For this you can create a trigger on `Parameters` that will [upsert](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) into `Inputs` on insert. If you ever delete or update this columns on `Parameters` then maintaining `Inputs` would be complicated. You'd have to delete rows when there's no corresponding row in `Parameters` - you'd need to maintain counts in `Inputs`, to know when there's no corresponding row in `Parameters`. Concurrent insert/update/delete performance will suck, as any change in `Parameters` will have to block a row in `Inputs`. This is all ugly and bad - a view is much better solution.